# Setting timer for a javascript randomizer

Tags: javascript, setinterval

The randomizer works, but looking for a way to get it to loop using the setInterval so it can continuously run in its own div on a website.

```
<script language="JavaScript">
setInterval(quotes(), 3000);
function quotes(i) {
    var r_text = new Array();
    r_text[0] = "All the leaves are brown";
    r_text[1] = "And the sky is grey";
    r_text[2] = "I've been for a walk";
    r_text[3] = "On a winter's day";
    r_text[4] = "I'd be safe and warm";
    r_text[5] = "If I was in L.A.";
    r_text[6] = "California dreaming, On such a winter's day";
    var i = Math.floor(7 * Math.random())
    document.write(r_text[i]);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

change `setInterval(quotes(), 3000);` to `setInterval(quotes, 3000);`

Answer (score 0):

### You need to fix your setInterval call function

change

```
 setInterval(quotes(), 3000);
```

to

```
  setInterval(quotes, 3000);
```

and the function will randomize every 3 seconds

Edit: Also, document.write() is deprecated and should be replaced with a different function for writing to the html.

second edit: you are also passing a parameter that is never used. Consider removing it.

Comment: Indeed. Remember OP, when you put () after the function name, you are calling that function and returning whatever it returns in its called place. Set interval needs to know the function object itself which it has to call every 3 seconds, which is expressed without parentheses.

Comment: Good clarification @V.Rubinetti . Thank you for expanding on () vs no (). I think it's important to have context whenever learning something new, not just "this is the way it is".

Comment: Just a note, `document.write()` isn't deprecated. It's been around for some time and will probably be around for the foreseeable future. However, as Steve noted, it's probably not what you want to use. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write

Comment: Thanks for fixing my words. Deprecated wasn't correct, but it should be avoided

Answer (score 0):

SetInterval requires a function call, the brackets in the call are causing it to execute the function and return the value to setInterval. Also, you don't need "i" as a parameter.

Try:

```js
setInterval(quotes, 3000);
function quotes() {
    var r_text = new Array();
    r_text[0] = "All the leaves are brown";
    r_text[1] = "And the sky is grey";
    r_text[2] = "I've been for a walk";
    r_text[3] = "On a winter's day";
    r_text[4] = "I'd be safe and warm";
    r_text[5] = "If I was in L.A.";
    r_text[6] = "California dreaming, On such a winter's day";
    var i = Math.floor(7 * Math.random())
    document.write(r_text[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your setInterval is incorrect.

```
setInterval(function(){quotes()}, 3000);

function quotes() {
    var r_text = new Array();
    r_text[0] = "All the leaves are brown";
    r_text[1] = "And the sky is grey";
    r_text[2] = "I've been for a walk";
    r_text[3] = "On a winter's day";
    r_text[4] = "I'd be safe and warm";
    r_text[5] = "If I was in L.A.";
    r_text[6] = "California dreaming, On such a winter's day";
    var i = Math.floor(7 * Math.random())   
    document.write(r_text[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var quotes = [
  "All the leaves are brown",
  "And the sky is grey",
  "I've been for a walk",
  "On a winter's day",
  "I'd be safe and warm",
  "If I was in L.A.",
  "California dreaming, On such a winter's day"
];

function getRandomQuote() {
  var index = Math.random() * quotes.length << 0;
  return quotes[index];
}

setInterval(function() {
  var quote = getRandomQuote();
  document.write(quote);
}, 3000);
```

This way splits the code up into logical sections; there is a function to get a random quote, and an anonymous function (inside the `setInterval`) to `document.write` it.  You can also use array shorthand to define your quotes, instead of definiting each separately (and redefining them each time every 3 seconds as other answers do).

`<< 0` is just a quick way to **chop off** (note: not rounding) the decimal of a number in Javascript.

Comment: `~~123.45` does the same chop off trick too :)  
Also, props for changing the array definition and the function name to a verb. Function names shouldn't be nouns.

I was doing pretty much the same thing here http://jsfiddle.net/bfbh5pb0/

Comment: @JacqueGoupil Nice!  I wonder if there are any performance differences between `<<` and `~~`.  I don't have access to jsPerf at the moment, unfortunately.

Comment: Just checked jsPerf with chrome. `>> 0` seems slightly quicker than both `~~x` and `<< 0`, but floor and round are faster.

Comment: Woah, I always thought the bitwise operations would massively exceed the speeds of Math functions.  Thanks!